# MySQL updating field based on datetime range from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, range

I have a table like

```
datetime             game   sum         Releated
01/03/2015 00:00:25  Game1  1342.75 
01/03/2015 00:01:52  Game2  1418.5  
01/03/2015 00:01:53  Game3  1289    
01/03/2015 00:04:41  Game4  1473.25 
01/03/2015 00:06:09  Game5  1581.25
```

to become something like this.

```
 datetime            game   sum         Releated
01/03/2015 00:00:25  Game1  1342.75 
01/03/2015 00:01:52  Game2  1418.5      01/03/2015 00:01:52
01/03/2015 00:01:53  Game3  1289        01/03/2015 00:01:52
01/03/2015 00:04:41  Game4  1473.25 
01/03/2015 00:06:09  Game5  1581.25
```

If two or more rows are within 10 seconds time difference (e.g: 2nd and 3rd row) I want to update related columns to mark it. Either with `datetime` or some value. Which mean that are the same row set.

or

Based on the same theory I want to sum the sum column if they are between 10 seconds range.

Comment: If these ranges come continuously after each other that make a range of 20 seconds what should it be? Please add some results to your question ;).

Comment: @shA.t added result set.

Comment: @Huey sorry it didnt work.

Comment: Why is in your related column of your outputs  you have only `...:01:52` and also it comes for itself ?

Comment: @shA.t it means these are the only 2 rows are 10 sec difference. not anything else.  and buy putting it in front of itself now i can select/group dataset which is whiten 10 sec range. So on each row i check if there any rows after that which are within 10 sec range. if they are i update releated column with datetime of first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT min(t2.d) 
   FROM yourTable t2
   WHERE ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t2.d, t1.d)) <= 10
         AND t2.d <> t1.d
  ) As related
FROM yourTable t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM harronLati a inner join harronLati b
WHERE
ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,a.datetime,b.datetime)) <= 10 
group by a.datetime,a.game,a.sum,a.Releated
```